# EditText not editable in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a fragment that contain a simple `EditText` and when I run my programm the `EdtiText` will be not `Editable` but if Edit it within the code it works like this :

```
myEditText.setText("COCO");
```

Also when I don't use fragment (mean in the normaly Activity) then the `EditText` will be Editable.
So my Layout that contain the `EDitText` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/search" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search_btn"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/search_setting" />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_eleuteurs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ListView>
```

it's called `search_text`.
and my fragment is :

```
public class ListElecteur extends Fragment {

private ListView listElecteurs;
private EditText search ;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_electeurs_fragment,
            container, false);

    return view;
}
```

ah, I forgot, when I typed in `myEditText` the current Tab take the focus so any thing wrote in `myEditText` :(.

and here is some screenshot to explain the problem.
first :

[image]

you saw here the cursor in `myEditText` and now if I will typed anything with my keybord see what happned:

[image]

here the EditText Lost the cursor and The `Tab(title)` becaume with color blue that's Like selected.

Comment: So I tested it in real device (phone) it works but in emulator doesn't work I don't know why , even I changed several emulator but the same problem :/. and here I share my example http://ge.tt/8I7wpGp1/v/0 please test it with emulator thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<requestFocus />` and put 0dp value in android:layout_width of EditText and Button

**Edit:**

This is my version of the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

     <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

          <EditText
               android:id="@+id/search_text"
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:ems="10"
               android:hint="@string/search" />

          <Button
               android:id="@+id/search_btn"
               style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
               android:layout_width="15dp"
               android:layout_height="40dp"
               android:background="@drawable/search_setting" />
     </LinearLayout>

     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/list_eleuteurs"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="1" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Try it! :D

Comment: I did what you said but the same problem, I think you don't understand me, I explain : I have a fragment contain EditText and when I will type in this EditText any caracter will be showed :(.

Comment: But when you click the edittext the keyboard comes up?

Comment: no, just the cursor is displayed and if I will type that's blocked and select the tab automatically :(.  @AlexBalo.

Comment: if you comment the listview out are you able to see the edittext?

Comment: No even I remove myListView is the same problem :(.

Answer (score 0):

Just a silly suggestion. Try enclosing your fragment layout xml under FrameLayout. Thats what I do while working with fragments. Sample:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fr"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="12pt"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv1" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.31"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I did enclosed my fragment with <FrameLayout> but the same prblem offffff I will be crazy why don't work even I stay only the the EditText in Layout, and if I don't use Fragment so with NormalyActivity it will work or with fragmentDialog it's fine work :(.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the AVD Manager,click on your device and click on edit. See if the "Hardware keyboard present" checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: I did but The same problem, even I create other project that contain a Fragment and only an EditText :( but also doesn't work

Comment: Ok. I did a little research on registering a focus listener for your EditText. I'm editing the answer. Tell if this works. Tweak the code according to your fragment.

Comment: when I will type, show me the toast with text loast the focus.

Comment: you can see my comment of my post @Sushant Sehgal, it work with device but doesn't work with emulator.

Comment: I don't think its a code problem then.. Probably something to do with your emulator. I am editing my answer check it out.

Comment: thanks to you, I cheked it and the same problem, I think it's a bug for emulators, then Emulators don't support tabhost, after that I found other solution is to change to ActionBar and use the viewer instead tabHost, and thanks a lot :)

Comment: Anytime! just upvote or mark as answered if you found me useful. Im new to stack overflow and need support !!